# php oop visibility: How the function in parent class calls it's own private function and child class public function

Tags: php, oop

I don't know how to ask this question, that's why the title is not. good please change it if anybody can..

It is in the PHP doc http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php under Method Visibility ¶

```
<?php

class Bar 
{
    public function test() {
        $this->testPrivate();
        $this->testPublic();
    }

    public function testPublic() {
        echo "Bar::testPublic\n";
    }

    private function testPrivate() {
        echo "Bar::testPrivate\n";
    }
}

class Foo extends Bar 
{
    public function testPublic() {
        echo "Foo::testPublic\n";
    }

    private function testPrivate() {
        echo "Foo::testPrivate\n";
    }
}

$myFoo = new Foo();
$myFoo->test(); // Bar::testPrivate 
                // Foo::testPublic
?>
```

In the above code how `$myFoo->test()` prints `Bar::testPrivate` and `Foo::testPublic`
I thought it will print `Foo::testPrivate` and `Foo::testPublic`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `private` method or property can only be accessed from exactly the same class that it's defined in. `Bar::testPrivate` can only be called from `Bar`, that's what *`private`* means. Conversely, `Foo::testPrivate` can only be called from code that is literally within the `Foo` class definition.

Since `Bar::test` is in `Bar`, it cannot call `Foo::testPrivate`. The only implementation that it can call is `Bar::testPrivate`. The `public` method however has no such restrictions and the overridden method of the child class is called.

If you overrode the `test` method in `Foo`, the situation would reverse:

```
class Foo extends Bar {
    public function test() {
        $this->testPrivate();
        $this->testPublic();
    }

    ...
}
```

Now the code is literally within `Foo` and could only call `Foo::testPrivate`.

Answer (score 0):

Private = visible to objects created from this class,and not visible to the outside world

Protected = visible to all classes and objects inherited from this class, but not visible to the outside world (what you are looking for)

Public= visible everywhere